# Run prediction with subset of features

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using the tf.estimator.LinearClassifier can you run predict on a model with a sub set of features ?

Crated a model with 5 features but want to run a prediction with 2 features ?

```
ValueError: Feature capital_gain is not in features dictionary.
```

Comment: First of all, add the data and the code. the answer to your question is no, you cannot fit a model with 5 features and then make predictions for samples with 2 features

Comment: Its a general question so no need to add the data files and my code. Thanks anyhow for quick reply.